# Running python commands from EMR workspace never completes / errors using pyspark notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, boto3, amazon-emr

I have a emr ec2 cluster connected to a studio / workspace. I can successfully run the notebook example of `word-count-with-pyspark` but when trying to run something with boto3 or pandas it never finishes?

If i run a `%pip list` i can see both `boto3` and `pandas` are listed. The IAM roles that runs as the service account for EMR Stuido and the EMR cluster both have a section with:

```
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```

### Boto3

[image]

### pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('s3://xxx/test/orgs.csv')
print(df.to_string())
```

returns:

```
An error was encountered:
No module named 'pandas'
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

But i would also presume it would time out / fail if it was a permissions issue? Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a couple of possible causes. I am by no means an expert but I and my team have been using SageMaker Studio with EMR for the past 8 months, so these are my tips what to try to fix in my experience:

> The IAM roles that runs as the service account for EMR Stuido and the EMR cluster both have a section with:

EMR has 2 role types: EMR Service role, and EMR EC2 Instance role. You need to make sure that the relevant permissions are granted to the EMR EC2 instance role (e.g. to read a particular S3 bucket), because that is the role assumed by the EC2 instances which run Spark.

For the Boto3 problem, my bet is that your EMR EC2 role does not have sufficient permissions, and the call is stuck in exponential back-off retry, and if you wait long enough, you should get stack trace exception whose root cause is Access Denied. For me, the easiest way to debug this has been to SSH to the leader node via AWS Systems Manager, and run Spark Shell there. I would get more informative stack traces that way. The alternative way would be to query CloudTrail - you should see Access Denied events for S3 service.

For the Pandas problem, my bet is that Pandas is installed on the Python kernel of the notebook, but not on the EC2 instances of the cluster, but I could be wrong. Note that your Jupyter server webapp connects to Python kernel instance which is a hosted EC2 instance **outside** of the EMR cluster. Then, that kernel/EC2 instance connects on your behalf to the cluster. The easiest way to verify whether or not pandas is actually installed on your EMR cluster is by SSHing to the leader node, then running `python3` there, and importing pandas there.

If it is not, you have 2 options for how to fix that:

1. Run a bootstrap action that installs pandas on all instances
2. In our case, because I work in a company whose security does not allow installing packages from wider internet via `pip`, we build a Docker image that the EMR cluster uses, and that has Pandas. I don't recommend this if you can just run `pip install pandas` because that's for sure a lot simpler solution.